# Sign the XML file in UWP application

Tags: uwp, windows-store-apps, win-universal-app

I need to verify the digitally signed xml file in UWP application.I have used RSA algorithm to digitally sign the xml file. But, the UWP application does not support RSA algorithm. Is there any way to verify the digitally sign the XML file and verify it in UWP application.

Answer (score 0):

.net core 2.0 has integrated the relevant APIs:https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/?view=netcore-2.0&term=System.Security.Cryptography.Xml, but .net core 2.0 doesn't support in UWP.

Microsoft says they will intend for UWP to support .NET Standard 2.0 later this year(see https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/dotnet/2017/05/10/announcing-net-core-2-0-preview-1/). But I cannot find the relevant APIs in .NET Standard 2.0.

So, I think there's no way to do it in UWP.